# [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown type "postsConnection"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am trying to use fragments to reuse my graphql code but its not working although before using fragment code works fine.

This is how my code looks like

> fragments.js

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export const postFragment = gql`
    fragment PostData on postsConnection {
        edges {
            node {
                id
                title
                date
                featuredImage {
                    sourceUrl
                }
            }
        }
    } `
```

> this is my query file  queries/posts.js

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import {postFragment} from '../fragments';


export const getAllPosts = gql`
  query getAllPosts {
    posts {
      ...PostData
    }
  }
  ${postFragment}
`;
```

This is the error get

> [GraphQL error]: Message: Unknown type "postsConnection"., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Language.Fragments):

> Fragments must specify the type they apply to... Fragments cannot be specified on any input value (scalar, enumeration, or input object). Fragments can be specified on object types, interfaces, and unions. Selections within fragments only return values when concrete type of the object it is operating on matches the type of the fragment.

A fragment must specify the type it applies to, and that type must actually exist in your schema. Based on the error you're seeing, `postsConnection` is not a valid type. Check the documentation for your schema or run an introspection query to determine the correct type for the `posts` field.

A simple introspection query to get the names and types of all fields for the Query type:

```
query GetQueryFields {
  __schema {
    queryType {
      fields {
        name
        type {
          name
          kind
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont have schema file i am quering data from wordpress.

Comment: I dont have schema file i am quering data from wordpress.

Comment: As suggested, you can use an introspection query to get information about the schema. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: i did not get this  does that mean i should not use frament ?

Comment: You can use a fragment, you just need to know the type. Make a request to the endpoint using the above introspection query to determine the type of the `posts` field. If the endpoint exposes a GraphiQL or GraphQL playground interface, you could also just check the type for the field that way. It's probably `PostsConnection`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: thank you @Daniel it was **RootQueryToPostConnection**